# Powering ir led with a 9V battery

Tags: arduino, infrared

I'm using this break beam https://www.adafruit.com/product/2168 with an arduino. Currently both sides are are powered by the 5V from the arduino. I want to move the led half of the break beam to the far side of a doorway so it can be used to count foot traffic. Is there a way to hook up the ir led to a 9V battery without using a breadboard? Can I use electrical tape to affix a resistor between the battery and the led? Here is my project page https://devpost.com/software/door-counter thank you in advance for any advice on how to power the led separately from the the receiver.

Comment: Your experiment seems to overlook that IR systems unshielded from ambient light that seek to have any meaningful range use *modulated* signals, so to do this right you'll need a driver that switches the LED at something like 38 KHz and a receiver that looks for that.  Your unmodulated system *might* work but it may be very susceptible to environment conditions.  At the least try to make opaque "telescope tubes" so the receiver sees only the emitter.

Comment: @ChrisStratton suggests a superior solution using TV-remote type circuits: range is much increased (up to 10 M) and current consumption of the transmitter is much reduced. The receiver is a 3-pin chip that very simply interfaces with your arduino. Transmitter circuit is considerably more complex: One chip plus half-a-dozen resistors and capacitors, plus an infrared LED.

Comment: Chris and Glen, these are great suggestions. I assumed that this was a dedicated frequency unit because it's not passive IR. Does anyone have a link or a product name for the TV remote type ir with the longer range?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can but you have a few problems. A 9 V battery will discharge quickly when continuously driving the infra-red LED. And making electrical connections to a 9 V battery requires a snap-on battery connector. 
[image: 9 V battery clip]
Soldering is the only reliable way to connect the LEDtransmitter + resistor to the battery snap-on connector. But if you insist on proceeding, here's the circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhwEn3.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

An alternative circuit is shown, using two batteries in series (1.5 V each) that will last somewhat longer, yet still provide similar light intensity. Note that the 180 ohm resistor is contained inside the transmitter module. I'm guessing the internal circuit, since ADAfruit don't provide details.
Since the light beam expands as it travels further, you may find that detecting the beam across a doorway may be difficult, and will require larger current from the battery (too much for the LED to dissipate).

"Electrical tape" is used because of its protective insulating properties, not because it promotes electrical contact. It should not be used to secure a wrapped connection - reliability is not assured. Soldering or crimping is more reliable.

Comment: Glen, thank you for the thoughtful reply. I have a snap on connector like the one you pictured, and I feel confident soldering, so I might try that. I will also look into AA battery packs in case that works better. I read somewhere to never connect batteries in series because one could discharge into the other. Maybe someone with an EE degree could do that safely...but I'll stick to the pre-made battery cases. It looks like there is a resistor inside the unit, here is the datasheet https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/product-files/2168/C2917.pdf

Answer (score 0):

IR LED starts from 1.2~1.6V depending if pulsed up to 100mA with an ESR near 5 ohms, so 9V is very inefficient.

That's why LiPo 3.6V is preferred or some other low ESR , low voltage source. 9V is higher V ,higher ESR source, thus lower mAh capacity in terms of density or size.  You can trickle charge with 3.7~3.9V without fancy charger, if you can use adequate super low dropout , 3.3V LDO on arduino.

Comment: Thanks, Tony. In the product description for this led it says it is possible to power with 3V, but the range decreases. I wanted to cover the width of a door so I need a three foot range. I will test with the 3.6 Lipo to see what range I can get. Thanks for the quick reply!

Comment: Using LiPo batteries correctly is a bit challenging.  You would be better off with multiple rechargeable AA cells - this also lets you tune the number, for example you can use 2 or 3.

Comment: I,am not sure where current limiting R is located. Inside emitter? but( 5V-1.4)/20mA =180 Ohms including driver ESR. using their values...although IR LEDs are usually rated for 50mA DC but high drain unless narrow pulse duty cycle.  Rx 10k affects gain and pulse response bandwidth

Comment: Tony, it looks like the built in resistor is on the receiver side in the data line. I don't understand why it is there.... to protect the receiver from damage if accidentally getting the data line plugged into the ground maybe? Here is the data sheet https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/product-files/2168/C2917.pdf How can I change the pulse duty cycle to make it narrow? Is that something I can do in software?

Comment: It appears this product has more inside than Glen has shown. I think output is like Open Collector and you cannot deviate from the Power Voltage: 3.3 - 5.5VDC and you must try to supply 5V. If Sensing Distance: Approx 50cm / 20" is not reliable, I have a better design but more complex. using pulse patterns and IRDA chip and count data errors in narrow beam communication sending 6 bits or so at 10 to 100kbps but I only use Rx side of IRDA pair and it uses more current on Tx side

Comment: Tony, yes the receiver is open collector. I am using an arduino uno which has a built in pull up resistor that I turn on with a line of code. I'm interested in seeing your idea for a different way to power the transmitter separately. I wonder if it can be pushed to transmit farther with increased power but I am obviously nervous about breaking it. I have broken plenty of leds with too much power, but this one is more expensive.

Comment: I once implemented this with an 8bit PIC 100mA 10% duty cycle IR LED and an IRDA shielded Sharp transceiver using only the Rx with a synchronous data pattern and look for bit errors meant path interrupted. Bit period determines energy per bit and thus path loss is controllable with bit rate using RZ pulse modulation. You can use 50% Bi-Phase as well and burst  communication at 20% duty cycle to not exceed 20mA average or push it to 50mA average, within its SOA.

Comment: You want an LED in the smallest angle like 8 deg span your target Rex's  with synchronized Tx in TDM unique patterns so any path blocked to any Rx indicates interruption line of sight. This gives one laser like precision with recessed parts in a 5mm aperture or wider beamwidth according to layout of design and path needing detection.  Otherwise use CW carrier and detect AGC changes that represent reflections or blocking with a window comparator that adjusts slowly with LED aging. It is trivial to protect IR LED average overcurrent current

Answer (score 0):

I might use a battery for a short-term test, but for any permanent or long-term installation, I would want the whole system, including the LED, powered from AC.  Otherwise you will have to replace the battery frequently, and won't know the battery needs replacement until you realize the counter is not working.

Comment: Peter, I agree. What you describe is definitely a mark in favor of powering both sides of the break beam from one outlet.